# Get IDs of Multiple <td> in a <tr> with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in my html:

```
<table id = 'manifest-table25' class="manifest-table2" width=100%>
                  <tbody width=100%>
                    <tr class="manifest-row">
                      <td width = 17.5%>{{form2.ProductCode}}</td>
                      <td width = 32.5%>{{form2.DescriptionOfGoods}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="quantity">{{form2.UnitQty}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.Type}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% oninput="calculate()">{{form2.Price}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.Amount}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have a function `calculate()` called oninput to the Price field, which multiplies UnitQty * Price and displays the result in Amount.

```
<script>

    function calculate() {
      var UnitQty = document.getElementById('id_form-0-UnitQty').value;
      var Price = document.getElementById('id_form-0-Price').value;
      var LineTotal = UnitQty * Price;
      $('#id_form-0-Amount').val(LineTotal);
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly, but is hardcoded to use those specific IDs. My dilemma is that the user has the ability to dynamically add rows to this table, and this will work only for one row.  So if the user adds one more row, obviously the above is hardcoded and doesn't apply for that new row. The function called for the new row would need to effectively look like this:

```
<script>

    function calculate() {
      var UnitQty = document.getElementById('id_form-1-UnitQty').value;
      var Price = document.getElementById('id_form-1-Price').value;
      var LineTotal = UnitQty * Price;
      $('#id_form-1-Amount').val(LineTotal);
}
</script>
```

So I need some way to dynamically pick replace the IDs in that function, based on which  is actually being typed in.  I am completely stuck on thinking up an approach, can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Your code *seems* to treat `td` elements like `input` elements. Please show us an example of what the DOM looks like *as the browser sees it*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the `{{...}}` create `input` elements within those `td` elements.

A minimal change is to change

```
oninput="calculate()"
```

to

```
oninput="calculate(this)"
```

which passes the element the event was fired by into the function, then use DOM navigation within the function:

```
function calculate(el) {
    // Find the row containing this cell
    var row = el.closest("tr");
    // Get the quantity from the `input` in the `.quantity` cell in this row
    var unitQty = row.querySelector('.quantity input').value;
    // Get the price from the `input` in this cell (could use `e.target` instead)
    var price = el.querySelector('input').value;
    // Do the calculation, assign to the `input` in the `.amount` cell in this row
    var lineTotal = unitQty * price;
    row.querySelector(".amount input").value = lineTotal;
}
```

(Note: I've updated that code to follow standard JavaScript variable naming conventions.)

To avoid making that really fragile, I've added a class to the final `td` for that last `querySelector` call.

Or if you prefer jQuery:

```
function calculate(el) {
    // Find the row containing this cell
    var row = $(el).closest("tr");
    // Get the quantity from the `input` in the `.quantity` cell in this row
    var unitQty = row.find('.quantity input').val();
    // Get the price from the `input` in this cell (could use `e.target` instead)
    var price = $(el).find('input').val();
    // Do the calculation, assign to the `input` in the `.amount` cell in this row
    var lineTotal = unitQty * price;
    row.find(".amount input").val(lineTotal);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply -  your assumptions were correct! very helpful.  the only thing that seems to not work here is ```row.querySelector(".amount").value = lineTotal;``` I printed everything else to the console and found that each of the variables are being set properly but the .amount input doesn't get populated.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @GXM100 - See my note *"To avoid making that really fragile, I've added a class to the final td for that last querySelector call."* -- you need to add that class to that `td` so it matches. I should have been more explicit about that.

Comment: You're mentioning the ```.amount``` class correct? If so I did add this with no luck!

Comment: Ah I see I had to amend that to ```row.find(".amount input").val(lineTotal);``` and that solved it.  thank you !

Comment: @GXM100 - Doh! I've fixed the answer, sorry about that. :-)